# Make better solution for Bean counting example from "Eloquent JavaScript" book

Tags: closure

How can this code be improved by "closuring" of functions here?

```js
// Your code here.
let countBs = countChar();

function countChar(str, letter = 'B') {
  if (letter === 'B') return (str, letter = 'B') => String(str).split('').filter(ltr => ltr == letter).length;
  return String(str).split('').filter(ltr => ltr == letter).length;
}

console.log(countBs("BBC"));
// → 2
console.log(countChar("kakkerlak", "k"));
// → 4
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Did you take this code from [the book](https://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/03_functions.html#h_3rsiDgC2do) or is this code that you wrote? If you wrote the code please explain that in the description above it.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Thank you. I've wrote this code by myself. OK, I'll try to edit.